# Can the intent limit be increased in Dialogflow?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, api-ai

The intent limit per agent is 2,000 as documented on https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas.

So I have multiple questions regarding this:

- Are the followup intents(hierarchical) counted as an intent? If I have very long conversations created with the help of follow-up intents. Let's assume each conversation has around 100 follow-up intents, does it means, I can only have 20 conversations in an agent.
- If the above statement is true, so can the intent limit be increased as per business requirements.
- Is there any other alternative to salve this?

Comment: you can use slot filling and fulfilment to reduce the count

Comment: I'm curious: can you give an example of a conversation with 100 intents?  I think I will get bored talking with a chatbot if it wants to match 100 intents to get me to whatever the final action is.

Answer (score 2):

- As for the [follow-up intent documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents), it is stated that *"A follow-up intent is a child of its associated parent intent."* I think with this we can identify that a follow-up intent is still an intent and will be counted as one.
- According to their [*Quotas and Limits*](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas) page, you can request for a higher quota. I'm not sure if this will increase the intent quota, but you can probably send them an email for your assurance.

> *To request a higher quota, click an edit button for a quota on the Quotas tab of the Google Cloud Platform Dashboard, and then click Apply for a higher quota in the quota edit form to submit a Dialogflow Quota Increase Request.*

- Instead of using follow-up intents, as stated by @Nikhil Savaliya, you could use [slot filling](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook-slot-filling), [contexts](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) (contexts are used by follow-up intents). You should probably also set up [fulfillment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) which uses a webhook to, well, *fulfill* your user's request.

How can these help, you ask?

**Slot Filling** 
Instead of asking the user separate information with different intents, ask them all using only one intent by slot-filling.

For example, instead of asking a user's name on one intent, then his/her age on another follow-up intent, ask them both on one single intent.

**Contexts and Fulfillment** 
Follow-up intents use context so that it knows where the conversation is. Similarly, you could only use one follow-up intent that uses the same context to deliver a proper response. You deliver this response by using a fulfillment.

For example, you ask the user "Are you human?"; one way of doing this in the Dialogflow console is that you add two follow-up intents, for a "Yes" and a "No" answer.

The other way you could do this is by code using fulfillment. Make sure your fulfillment webhook is ready to go.

1. Set the "Are you human?" intent's output context
2. Create a single intent (or a custom follow-up intent) and set it's input context to whatever the question's output context is. Enable fulfillment for this intent.
3. In your code, distinguish whether the user answered a 'yes' or a 'no', and then provide a proper response.

Please refer to [Dialogflow's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/) on how to code and do this properly.